# How to correctly recover date from SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, date

I created a simple CRUD using ASP.NET MVC and I can save my registers normally.
If I look in the Data Base my date was stored like that:

> 2017-06-01 00:01:23.750

But when I try to Edit the same register whith an async method created by MVC Scaffolding the date appears to bel null:

> 01/01/0001 00:00:00

Then (of course) I get an error:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

Thats the async method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "ArtigoId,Titulo,Texto,DataPublicacao,UltimaModificacao,UsuarioModificacao,DataCriacao,UsuarioCriacao")] Artigo artigo)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(artigo).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(artigo);
}
```

Why does it happen? How to correctly recover the date from data base?

**EDIT:**

I changed in Data Base for `datetime2(0-7)` but that made it accept the value **01/01/0001 00:00:00** and what I want is to know why this value appears instead of **2017-06-01 00:01:23.750**.

All the others values in the data base is recovered normally, but not this date.

Comment: `datetime` doesn't support `0001-01-01`. Use the `datetime2(0-7)` data type in your database. Or replace `0001-01-01` with an actual `null` value instead of the minimum value.

Comment: The dates in the sql server are valid only from 01/01/1900

Comment: @SqlZim I changed in DB for `datetime2(0-7)` but that made it accept the value `01/01/0001 00:00:00` and what I want is to know why this value appears instead of `2017-06-01 00:01:23.750`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurred because I removed my field in the View and there is nothing to do with the date format in **SQL Server**.

I put the field back in the **view** as **readyonly**:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataCriacao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataCriacao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataCriacao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

The search of the field in the DB is done in the GET method:

```
// GET: Artigos/Edit/5
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(Guid? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Artigo artigo = await db.Artigoes.FindAsync(id);
    if (artigo == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(artigo);
}
```

The method I posted was POST after the submit of my button to save the changes and no searches were done on the database.